# Manual AIC calculation vs LassoLarsIC

Tags: python, lasso-regression

I am trying to calculate AIC manually, but my function gives different scores compared to the LassoLarsIC score. Can someone tell me what is wrong with my calculation.

Here my function:

```
def aic(y_pred, y, k):
    ll = (-1/(2*np.var(y)))*np.sum((y_pred-y)**2) - (len(y)/2)*np.log(np.var(y)) - (len(y)/2)*np.log(2*np.pi)
    return -2*ll + 2*k
```

Thanks a lot

Edit:

My example is simple, here is the complete code:

```
X = np.array([0, 0.1111, 0.2222, 0.3333, 0.4444, 0.5556, 0.6667, 0.7778, 0.8889, 1]).reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.array([0.0528,  0.798 ,  0.8486,  0.8719,  0.1732, -0.3629, -0.7528, -0.9985, -0.6727, -0.1197]).reshape(-1, 1)
poly = plf(9)
F = poly.fit_transform(X)[:, 1:]
scl = StandardScaler()
F = scl.fit_transform(F)
aic_lasso = LassoLarsIC(normalize=False)
aic_lasso.fit(F, y)
aic_lasso.criterion_
```

Output:

```
array([10.        ,  7.29642036,  8.9544056 ,  7.06390981,  6.14233987,
        7.96489293,  7.76894903,  7.61736515,  7.39575925,  7.25866825,
        7.01418447,  6.90314784,  6.6465343 ,  6.60361937,  8.12547536,
        8.09620652,  8.09610375, 10.09599191, 12.0959849 , 12.09597075,
       12.09596367, 12.09579736, 10.09579645, 10.09579616, 12.09579393,
       12.09579199, 12.09579079, 14.09541338, 16.01988119])
```

```
y_pred = aic_lasso.predict(F)
aic(y_pred, y, 2)
```

Output:

```
146.42615433502792
```

K is 2 becuase, lasso sets the other coeff. to 0.

Comment: Can you add some example input and the expected output (i.e., the LassoLarsIC output)? Please also note the hints described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Maybe you have to change  `- (len(y)/2)*np.log(2*np.pi) return -2*ll + 2*k` into `+(len(y)/2)*np.log(2*np.pi) return -2*ll + 2*k`

Comment: Hi @Nifriz , I do not understand how that is going to help since likelihood function defined with minus rather than plus.

Comment: Lasso Model: `(1 / (2 * n_samples)) * ||y - Xw||^2_2 + alpha * ||w||_1`

Comment: @Nifriz, that is the loss function of lasso obtained from negative log-likelihood by adding punishment term. I do not see the relation between the sign of that term and the loss function.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this answer arrives way too late, but the mistake is that you use `var(y)` instead of `std(residuals)`

This will work

```
    def aic(resid, nparams):
        n = len (resid)
        sig = np.std(resid)
        ll = -n*np.log(sig*np.sqrt(np.pi*2))- np.sum((resid / sig)**2)/2
        return float(2*nparams - 2*ll)
```